# How does use a conditional(if or while) for replacing values in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to work with this a data that has information about price electricity. The price is registered each 5 minutes. My objective is replace the negative values with the mean of the day.

```
year month   day fivemin rrp_nsw rrp_qld rrp_sa rrp_tas rrp_vic
2009     7     1       1    16.9    17.6   16.7    15.7    15.5
2009     7     1       2    17.7    18.8   17.8    -16.1    15.5
2009     7     1       3    -17.7    18.6   18.1    15.9    15.4
2009     7     1       4    16.7    18.6   -17.6    14.3    12.8
2009     7     2       1    -15.6    17.6   16.3    13.2    11.8
2009     7     2       2    13.7    15.7   12.0    -11.1    -12.9
2009     7     2       3    13.7    15.8   11.9    11.1    12.9
2009     7     2       4    -13.9    16.1   -12.1    11.2    12.9
2009     8     1       1    13.8    16.0   12.2    11.2    12.8
2009     8     1       2    -13.7    16.3   11.6    10.6    12.6
2009     8     1       3    13.7    -15.8   11.9    11.0    12.7
2009     8     1       4    13.8    16.0   12.1    11.2    12.9
2009     8     2       1    17.6    -17.6   17.3    16.5    17.1
2009     8     2       2    17.7    17.6   17.3    16.8    17.4
2009     8     2       3    15.8    16.0   15.1    15.0    15.5
2009     8     2       4    -15.4    15.6   14.5    14.6    15.1
2009     9     1       1    14.7    15.0   13.8    14.0    14.5
2009     9     1       2    15.3    15.4   14.3    14.6    15.0
2009     9     1       3    15.3    15.6   14.4    14.5    15.0
2009     9     1       4    14.9    15.7   13.7    13.8    14.5
```

In order to obtain the mean of each day I use the following code

```
Daily_mean<-Base %>%
arrange(year, month, day, fivemin) %>% #we are ordering the data 
group_by(year, month, day)%>%
summarise_at(
vars(c(rrp_nsw, rrp_qld, rrp_sa, rrp_tas, rrp_vic)),
.funs = funs(mean(.)))
```

When I get the daily mean I want to replace each negative value with the mean of the day. For example using the 16th observation

```
2009     8     2       4    "8.925"    15.6   14.5    14.6    15.1
```

If someone can help me i would be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `replace` in `mutate_at` to change the negative values to `mean` of that column after grouping by the relevant columns

```
library(dplyr)
Base %>%
  arrange(year, month, day, fivemin) %>% 
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(rrp_nsw, rrp_qld, rrp_sa, rrp_tas, rrp_vic), 
          ~ replace(., . < 0, mean(.)))
```